# How to set table not to collapse when i minimize the browser ! in vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net

How to set table not to collapse when i make the size of browser smaller ! in vb.net

Answer (score 0):

you should set table width to static

ex: `<table width="1000px">`

Answer (score 0):

You should use [table-layout:fixed](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_tab_table-layout.asp) CSS with static width of cells.

```
<table style="table-layout:fixed">
 <tr>
  <td style="width:25%">width:25%...longtext...longtext...longtext...</td>
  <td style="width:120px">width:120px longtext...longtext...longtext...</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```